# iOS7 Custom transition called twice

Tags: ios, ios7, uitabbarcontroller, transition

I want to animate the transitions between the tabs of a `UITabBarController`. For some reason this method from the `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` protocol is called twice:

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
```

The stacktrace:
[image]
And  immediately after:
[image]
Also the `- (void)animationEnded:(BOOL)transitionCompleted` method is called twice.

I have no ideea why.

This is the code:

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {

    UIView *containerView = [transitionContext containerView];

    UIViewController *fromVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *toVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

    [toVC.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(320, 0)];

    [containerView addSubview:toVC.view];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        [toVC.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];
        [fromVC.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-320, 0)];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [fromVC.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];
        [toVC.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];
        [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
    }];

}
```

Comment: How do you start the transition? Segue? Call method?

Answer (score 0):

For a first impression I believe `- (void)animationEnded:(BOOL)transitionCompleted` is called twice because you call `[transitionContext completeTransition:YES]` , which based on apple docs:

> Call this method after your animations have completed to notify the system that the transition animation is done. The default implementation of this method calls the animator’s **animationEnded**: method to give it a chance to perform any last minute cleanup.

And if `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` is called twice then here you go.

For further analysis of why `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` is called twice i would be happy to see your `animationControllerForPresentedController` and `animationControllerForDismissedController` implementation.